# Ternary Operator with Exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, conditional-operator

I often find myself writing code such as:

```py
try:
    name = names[2]
except IndexError:
    name = names[1]
```

or maybe:

```py
try:
    name = Names.first
except AttributeError:
    name = Names.default
```

Since there is a nice syntax for ternary operators, I wondered if there was something similar for exceptions? Something like:

```py
name = names[2] except IndexError names[1]

name = Names.first except AttributeError Names.default
```

which fits with the ternary operator style of:

```py
name = names[2] if names[2] else names[1]
```

Comment: Their is no such syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no expressions for dealing with exceptions (though there is a [rejected PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) that tried to introduce one). You can, however, avoid the exception in the first place.

```
name = names[2:0:-1][0]  # At the cost of making a small temporary list object
```

Assuming `names` has at least 2 values, the slice produces a list whose first element is either `names[2]` or `names[1]`, depending on how many elements `names` actually has. Whichever one is the first element of the slice is retrieved using `[0]`.

There's also no equivalent to `dict.get` that would let you write something like `names.get(2, names[1])`, though that suggests that perhaps your list *should* be a `dict` or something with more semantic structure.

Comment: Yeah that PEP is basically exactly what I wanted. Shame, but I understand the rejection. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax doesn't exist, but you can do something similar:

To handle `IndexError`, check if the index is within range:

```
name = names[2 if 2 in range(len(names)) else 1]
```

To handle `AttributeError`, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with default value:

```
name = getattr(Names, 'first', Names.default)
```

Edit: As @chepner suggested, the first might be simplified to these as well:

```
name = names[2 if len(names) > 2 else 1]

name = names[min(len(names), 2)] # if len(names > 0) and you just want the last element.
```

Comment: `2 if len(names) > 2 else 1` would be a bit simpler. You could even go with `min(len(names), 2)` if you can assume that `len(names) > 0`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I like the first suggestion but the latter have some assumptions tied to it (`len(names) > 0`) and default is last element).  I've edited my answer with your suggestions.